# Does Warslinger work with the Halfling Sling Staff?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

The halfling racial trait Warslinger reads:

> Warslinger: Halflings are experts at the use of the sling. Halflings with this racial trait can reload a sling as a free action. Reloading a sling still requires two hands and provokes attacks of opportunity. This racial trait replaces sure-footed.

Does this work with a Halfling Sling Staff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No.

Warslinger only works with the regular sling.

This is clarified in the [FAQ for the Advanced Race Guide](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1gh#v5748eaic9qus):

> #### Halfling, Warslinger: What kind of slings does the this reload ability work with?
>
> The warslinger ability says, "Halflings with this racial trait can reload a sling as a free action." It doesn't say "any type of sling" or "all slings," just "a sling." **The ability only affects standard slings**, not halfling sling staffs or any other kind of sling.

(emphasis mine).

Answer (score 3):

By default, **no**, however, there is a feat from the Weapon Master's Handbook, [*Slipslinger Style*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/slipslinger-style-combat-style/) that allows the Warslinger racial trait to work with the Halfling Sling Staff:

> ## Slipslinger Style (Combat, Style)
>
> Prerequisite(s): Weapon Focus (sling) or weapon training (thrown) class feature, warslinger racial trait
>
> You gain a +1 bonus on damage rolls made with all types of slings, and don’t provoke attacks of opportunity when reloading a sling. **In addition, you treat all ranged and thrown weapons that have “sling” in their name as if they were slings for all feats and class abilities that require such weapons, as well as the warslinger racial trait**

(emphasis mine) The Halfling Sling Staff is an exotic ranged weapon with the word sling in it, so the feat applies.